# PyMongo select fields on a full-text search

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, full-text-search, pymongo

Folks,
I trying to use the *fields* argument on *find* method, I got the follow error code:

```
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'fields'
```

Code:

```
mongo.db.products.find({ '$text': { '$search': string } }, { 'score': { '$meta': 'textScore' } }, fields=('name', 'foo', 'bar',))
```

Without full-text search the *fields* argument works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For pymongo the "projection part" for the 'textScore' needs to be included in the "fields" specification in the full form:

```
mongo.db.products.find(
    { '$text': { '$search': string } },
    fields=({ 'name': 1, 'foo': 1, 'bar': 1, 'score': { '$meta': 'textScore' } )
)
```

Comment: This doesn't work pymongo 4.0.2 Please update the answer.

```collection.find(
    {"$text": {"$search": "keyword"}},
    fields=({"name": 1, 'score': { '$meta': 'textScore' }})
)```

Raises error:

```TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fields'```